# Whether an isomorphism fixes the elements of the ground field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $A:=k[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$. Now, let $M$ be a maximal ideal of $A$ and suppose $f:A/M\to k$ is an isomorphism. Then, is it true that $f(a+M)=a$ for all $a\in k$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is $k$-linear, this is clear from the definition. Otherwise, it is not necessarily true. Consider $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-algebras with $f$ an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra map between them sending $1\mapsto 1$, $i\mapsto -i$, and $x\mapsto 0$. Then $f(i+(x))=-i$.

Comment: Of course $f$ is assumed to be an isomorphism of $k$-algebras (since this is the structure which matters here).

Comment: I agree that if I was reading the first two sentences in an article or paper, I would assume so. However, the fact that this question was posted to math.stackexchange makes me think that any answer should be as clear as possible to help someone who appears to be just getting on their feet in this subject.